# Optimizing character array member swapping in C++

Tags: c++

```
char buffer[256];

for(int x = 0; x<256; x+=4)
{
char one = buffer[x];
char two = buffer[x+1];
char three = buffer[x+2];
char four = buffer[x+3];

buffer[x] = four;
buffer[x+1]=three;
buffer[x+2]= two;
buffer[x+3]=one;
}
```

How exactly would I optimize this?

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be optimized beyond this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::reverse`:

```
std::reverse(&buffer[x], &buffer[x + 4]);
```

Comment: That certainly optimises readibility, so +1.

Comment: It's a shame it has undefined behavior.  Calling `buffer[x + 4]` when there are only four elements left in `buffer` is a no-no.  It should be `buffer + x, buffer + x + 4`.  (But the basic idea is good.)